# How do I wrap my enchant.js game in phonegap (apache cordova)?

Tags: cordova, enchantjs

My enchant game begins with

```
enchant();
window.onload = function() {
  game = new Game(...);
  game.onload = function() {...};
  game.start();
}
```

Where do I put these lines in the cordova/phonegap setup?

Comment: I don't use enchant, but all code should be used after the deviceready event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait the `deviceready` event before executing your game/app:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    enchant();
    window.onload = function() {
    game = new Game(...);
    game.onload = function() {...};
    game.start();
}
```

See the [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) for more details about Cordova events.