# Plugin not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have installed Rand Dusing's BLE Cordova Plugin and following his example to initialize bluetooth but I cannot get past that. Here is my `index.js`

```js
var blePlugin = window.bluetoothle;

function bleInitialize() {
  var paramsObj = {
    request: true,
    statusReceiver: true
  };
  document.getElementById("BTHWStatus").innerHTML = 'Initialze BLE: Checking BT status...';
  blePlugin.initialize(bleInitializeSuccess, bleInitializeError, paramsObj);
  document.getElementById("BTHWStatus").innerHTML = 'Initialze BLE: Complete';
  return false;
}

function bleInitializeSuccess(obj) {
  if (obj.status == "enabled")
    document.getElementById("BTHWStatus").innerHTML = 'BT is turned ON';
  else
    document.getElementById("BTHWStatus").innerHTML = 'BLE:Initialize: Unexpected error';
}

function bleInitializeError(obj) {
  document.getElementById("BTHWStatus").innerHTML = "Initialize Error : " + JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

This is `index.html`

```html
<h3>Bluetooth Test App</h3>
<br>
<div>
  <a id="BTHWStatus">BT is turned OFF</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <span>Enable/Disable Bluetooth :</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="BTSelect">
  <button id="BTApply">Apply</button>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me if I have anything incorrect in the`index.js` file that may prevent the plugin to not work? I have verified that the plugin is installed correctly in the command prompt using command `cordova plugin`.

Are the callback functions coded correctly or did I miss something? I can get the `blePlugin.initialize` function to print `Initialze BLE: Checking BT status...` on the app page but nothing after that.

Thanks and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application code executed [after the `deviceready` event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32390838/3340702)? From your code I can't see it so the problem could be this.

If you don't wait for the `deviceready` event, the js code will work but the Cordova related functions will be not available.

Comment: Yes, the application code after `deviceready` is being executed and I can get the Device info (Cordova, Version, Model etc. from cordova-plugin-device), which I call in `deviceready`. I call the `bleInitialize` from deviceready as well.